# Popup overlay problems with same z-index parameter in container

Tags: html, css, overlay, z-index, layer

I've got this page http://jsfiddle.net/UFTSK/2/ When you hover at image there is popup block overlay bug. if I remove z-index in a tag ( http://jsfiddle.net/UFTSK/3/ ), all working correct. But in IE7 the same problem. Please help.

Comment: Just one sollution with jquery http://jsfiddle.net/KwB9k/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used jQuery to Dynamically update z-index of your popup and anchor and also change the position of the popup and here you go.

http://jsfiddle.net/KwB9k/

Comment: Great. I thought about this. I thought that it could have css sollution.

Comment: if your .info element is not dynamic then you can manually put z-index to every element

Comment: I look at your jquery. It's not good. I think this is better http://jsfiddle.net/KwB9k/2/

Comment: Its just that I don't want conflict in any of my z-index to avoid any more issue